# MongoDB find returning zero results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know this will be something small I'm missing, but would appreciate the help.

Here is my test script (node.js)

---

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myTestDB',
    function (err, db) {
        if (err)
            debugger;
        else {            
            db.collection('test', function (err, collection) {

                collection.save({ name: "danny" }, function () { debugger;});

                collection.find(function (err, results) {
                    if(results.items.length == 0){
                       ///======> always = 0 !!!! WHY?!!!!
                        debugger;
                    }
                });
            });

        }
        db.close();
    });
```

---

feel free to start your answer with "duh!"

Comment: one thing to note is that the debugger; inside the save callback "collection.save({ name: "danny" }, function () { debugger;});" never triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: you also need to move your `db.close();` call inside the `find` callback or you're closing the connection before you're done with it.

In your example, `results` is a cursor, not an array of docs, so you need to call `toArray` on it to iterate over the cursor and get the array of docs.  But you also need to put your `find` call inside the `save` callback.  Otherwise the `find` is executing before the `save` has completed.

So something like this instead:

```
collection.save({ name: "danny" }, function () {
    collection.find().toArray(function (err, results) {
        // results contains the array of docs

        // Now you can close the connection.
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: That makes sense Jonny. But as a mention in my comment above the callback for the save never gets triggered. maybe i have a problem there.... but that would explain the first time not working but next time i run it the record of the previous run is in the table... i will test again and get back to you

Comment: See my update--I also noticed you're closing your connection too soon.

Comment: you sir... rock! that was it. I was closing the connection before it had a chance to callback. i think you hit three birds with on stone. I'm rewriting and testing again but i think this will solve it.

Comment: just need to work on connection management so that i dont get a growing amount of connections that will eventually fail after a few minutes in production

Comment: Great.  Just open your connection and leave it open until your app shuts down as it's actually a connection pool that's designed to be left open and shared.

Comment: good to know.... makes my life easier. Johnny thanks for all the help things are working great now